# VBA - Delete Adjacent row in For loop

Tags: vba, loops

I have two problems:

1)

I am running a for loop in vba that will search rows for a specific condition. If that condition is met, it will copy the value of a cell from the row above (using the offset function) and paste it in the cell below.

Then I want it to delete the entire row above. I am having trouble combining the offset function with

```
entirerow.delete
```

The error i get is just "Syntax error"

Here is the code:

```
Sub rowdelete()

maxrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count



For Each rcell In Range("A2:A" & maxrow)
  If rcell.Value = "--" Then
  rcell.offset(-1,).EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next rcell

End Sub
```

2) In playing around with syntax to troubleshoot, i tried just running 
rcell.entirerow.delete

this worked, but I realized if there are two adjacent rows which should be both deleted, only the first will be deleted. I presume this is because the second row becomes the first row after deletion and is skipped as an iteration in the loop.

Are there easy ways to get around this? It is important that the rows preserve the sort order they are in before the loop starts.

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so, then please mark as correct, by clicking the green check mark beside the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard for loop that loops backwards.

```
Sub rowdelete()
dim maxrow as long
dim i as long

maxrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = maxrow To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 1).Value = "--" Then
    Rows(i - 1).Delete

  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

another method is to put all the rows into one range and delete it once:

```
Sub rowdelete()
Dim maxrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

maxrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = maxrow To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 1).Value = "--" Then
    Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(i - 1))
  End If
Next i
rng.Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```